# pandas: text analysis: Transfer raw data to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, python-re

I need to read lines from a text file and extract the
quoted person name and quoted text from each line.

lines look similar to this:

> "Am I ever!", Homer Simpson responded.

> Remarks:
>
> Hint: Use the returned object from the '`open`' method to get the file
> handler. Each line you read is expected to contain a new-line in the
> end of the line. Remove the new-line as following: `line_cln =line.strip()`

> There are the options for each line (assume one of these
> three options): The first set of patterns, for which the person name
> appears before the quoted text. The second set of patterns, for which
> the quoted text appears before the person. Empty lines.

> Complete the `transfer_raw_text_to_dataframe` function to return a
> dataframe    with the extracted person name and text as explained
> above.  The information is expected to be extracted from the lines of
> the given `'filename'` file.

> The returned dataframe should include two columns:
>
> - `person_name` - containing the extracted person name for each line.
> - `extracted_text` - containing the extracted quoted text for each line.
>
> The returned values:
>
> - dataframe - The dataframe with the extracted information as described above.
>
> - Important Note: if a line does not contain any quotation pattern, no information should be saved in the
>   corresponding row in the dataframe.

what I got so far: [edited]

```
def transfer_raw_text_to_dataframe(filename):

    data = open(filename)
    
    quote_pattern ='"(.*)"'
    name_pattern = "\w+\s\w+"
    
    df = open(filename, encoding='utf8')
    lines = df.readlines()
    df.close()
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=('person_name', 'extracted_text'))
    i = 0  

    for line in lines:
        quote = re.search(quote_pattern,line)
        extracted_quotation = quote.group(1)

        name = re.search(name_pattern,line)
        extracted_person_name = name.group(0)
        
        df2 = {'person_name': extracted_person_name, 'extracted_text': extracted_quotation}
        dataframe = dataframe.append(df2, ignore_index = True)

        dataframe.loc[i] = [person_name, extracted_text]
        i =i+1
            
    return dataframe
```

the dataframe is created with the correct shape, problem is, the person name in each row is: 'Oh man' and the quote is 'Oh man, that guy's tough to love.' (in all of them)
which is weird because it's not even in the txt file...

**can anyone help me fix this?**

**Edit:** I need to extract from a simple txt file that contains these lines only:

```
"Am I ever!", Homer Simpson responded.
"Hmmm. So... is it okay if I go to the women's conference with Chloe?", Lisa Simpson answered.
"Really? Uh, sure.", Bart Simpson answered.
"Sounds great.", Bart Simpson replied.
Homer Simpson responded: "Danica Patrick in my thoughts!"
C. Montgomery Burns: "Trust me, he'll say it, or I'll bust him down to Thursday night vespers."
"Gimme that torch." Lisa Simpson said.
"No! No, I've got a lot more mothering left in me!", Marge Simpson said.
"Oh, Homie, I don't care if you're a billionaire. I love you just because you're..." Marge Simpson said.
"Damn you, e-Bay!" Homer Simpson answered.
```

Comment: what are the syntax rules for determining a quoted person?  you can do a look behind regular expression to find the quote then look for certain following key words as a non capturing group then capture the persons name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possibly in such a way:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# do smth
with open("12.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    # print(data)
    
    # ########## findall text in quotes
    m = re.findall(r'\"(.+)\"', data)
    print("RESULT: \n", m)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'rep': m})
    print(df)
    
    # ##########  retrieve and replace text in quotes for nothing
    m = re.sub(r'\"(.+)\"', r'', data)
    
    # ##########  get First Name & Last Name from the rest text in each line
    regex = re.compile("([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+ [A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)")
    mm = regex.findall(m)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'author': mm})
    print(df1)

    # ########## join 2 dataframes
    fin = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
    print(fin)
```

all print just for checking (get them away for cleaner code).
Just "C. Montgomery Burns" is loosing his first letter...

Answer (score 0):

for loop in folder:

```
# All files acc. mask ending with .txt
print(glob.glob("C:\\MyFolder\\*.txt"))

mylist=[ff for ff in glob.glob("C:\\MyFolder\\*.txt")]  
print("file_list:\n", mylist)

for filepath in mylist:
   # do smth with each filepath
```

to collect all dfs you're getting from files - smth like this (e.g. reading csv-files by-mask):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

def dfs_collect():
  mylist=[ff for ff in glob.glob("C:\\MyFolder\\*.txt")]   # all files by-mask
  print("file_list:\n", mylist)

  dfa=pd.concat((pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', encoding='windows-1250', index_col=False) for file in mylist), ignore_index=True)
```

but to get the content of your files - the example of the content is needed... without the example of your txt file (having dummy_info but left its real structure), I doubt, that anybody will try to imagine how it should look like

Comment: added the contents of the txt file in question above.

Answer (score 0):

I think that following does what you need. Please verify whether the output is accurate. I'll explain any line that is unclear

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.tree import ParentedTree
import typing as t # This is optional

# Using `read_csv` to read in the text because I find it easier
data = pd.read_csv("dialog.txt", header = None, sep = "~", quoting=3)
dialouges = data.squeeze() # Getting a series from the above DF with one column

def tag_sentence(tokenized: t.List[str]) -> t.List[t.Tuple[str, str]]:
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)
    tagged = [(token, tag) if tag not in {"``", "''"} else (token, "Q") for token, tag in tagged]
    keep = {"Q", "NNP"}
    renamed = [(token, "TEXT") if tag not in keep else (token, tag) for token, tag in tagged]
    return renamed

def get_parse_tree(tagged_sent):
    grammar = """
    NAME: {<NNP>+}
    WORDS: {<TEXT>+}
    DIALOUGE: {<Q><WORDS|NAME>+<Q>}
    """
    cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
    parse_tree = cp.parse(tagged_sent)
    return parse_tree

def extract_info(parse_tree):
    ptree = ParentedTree.convert(parse_tree)
    trees = list(ptree.subtrees())
    root = ptree.root()
    
    for subtree in trees[1:]:
        if subtree.parent() == root:
            if subtree.label() == "DIALOUGE":
                dialouge = ' '.join(word for word, _ in subtree.leaves()[1:-1]) # Skipping quotaton marks
            if subtree.label() == "NAME":
                person = ' '.join(word for word, _ in subtree.leaves())
    
    return dialouge, person

def process_sentence(sentence):
    return extract_info(get_parse_tree(tag_sentence(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence))))

processed = [process_sentence(line) for line in dialouges]
result = pd.DataFrame(processed, columns=["extracted_text", "person_name"])
```

The resulting DataFrame looks like this:

[image]